# how do I build a loop with a button + textbox

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new, on python 2.7 how do I build a loop with a button + textbox?

for example:

I want the user to enter is name and then press "ok" button, I want his name to be printed 5 times.

I dont want the button to stuck while it perform the command.

thanks!

Comment: Are you using a specific GUI library? For example, are you using Tkinter or QT for Python?

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a loop on the button_click event then the button will get stuck, because the **Main thread** of your program is **looping**, then it is like a stand-by.

You can solve this problem creating another thread containing the loop action.

```
#add this on the top of your code to import the thread library
import thread
```

After that you are able to create the thread, but first you need to define the loop function:

```
#this is the thread function
def loopFunction():
    for x in range(5):
        #textbook_value is the variable where you have previously stored
        #the name inserted into the textbook
        print textbook_value

#insert that in your button click event
try:
    thread.start_new_thread(loopFunction)
except:
    print "Unable to start the thread!"
```

The second thread will run and your button will not get stuck, because the Main thread is not busy.

To improve your skills about multithreading programming look [here](https://medium.com/@nbosco/multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-in-python-c7dc88b50b5b).
You can also refer to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1/).